# Bottom Widget overflow in Column layout?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to display an ad using the admob_flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter, which basically allows me to display the ad just like any other widget.

Following the documentation, I added a widget within a column layout as below (relevant code only):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(fileName),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: (){
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                ...
              ),
              AdmobBanner(
                adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-39402560999XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX',
                adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(...)
```

As per documentation, this is all I have to do, but I get an overflow error as seen in screenshot below:

[image]

I tried wrapping these in `Expanded()` and `Flexible()` but that did not fix my problem?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `widgets` in a `scrollable view` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your `Widgets` in a `Scrollable Widget` so they can be scrolled when the contents exceeds the device screen's size.
I wrapped your widgets in a `SingleChildScrollView`, check the demo below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(fileName),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: (){
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView( // new line
          child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                ...
              ),
              AdmobBanner(
                adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-39402560999XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX',
                adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        )
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `Column` to `Listview`

Comment: Please update your answer to explain what this does and hoe it helps solve the problem in the question, so that your answer is helpful both for the OP and also other users who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListView , SingleChildScrollView or ListView.builder if you want dynamic contents in place of Column

```
   body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Column(..),),
```